# How should i deal with presentView when i receive remote notification and try to back my rootviewcontroller to push next viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

1. present a viewcontroller and then lock the screen(the present view never be pushed into self.navigationviewcontroller.viewcontroller)
2. lock my iphone screen
3. send a promotion info
4. slide my remote notification
5. wish my app can dismiss the presentview and back to rootviewcontroller, then do some action (push a viewcontroller or present a new viewcontroller).

Question:
can't find the presentview to dismiss it

Comment: If `UINavigationController` is your rootController,  you can try to use this selector `popToViewController:`  or `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` to back to specific view controller

Comment: To find presentView, you can try this code : `UIViewController *modalVC = [[(UINavigationController*)controlelr topViewController] presentedViewController];`

Comment: @SeraZheng Thx, i find the property presentedViewController in uinavigationviewcontroller